# Музыка в консоли на С++

Tags: c++, mp3

Возник вопрос - Как запустить mp3-трек в консоли?
Погуглил и все ответы были на тему "установить какие-то библиотеки и они будут на фоне подгружать треки".
Есть какое-то решение без доп.установок ( желательно с примером ) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253074/how-to-play-or-open-mp3-or-wav-sound-file-in-c-program

Comment: Ничего не вывел для себя!

Answer (score 1):

С использованием Qt:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
// ...
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/me/Music/coolsong.mp3"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html

Без сторонних библиотек не выйдет. Нужно парсить мп3-файл, гнать в звуковой кодек, и еще много всего. Самое простое - что-нибудь типа Qt. Если нужна какая-то более сложная обработка звука - тогда GStreamer.